# Removing duplicates based on attribute values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C index="0">
                <element index="0">one</element>
                <element index="1">two</element>
                <keyElement index="1">key</keyElement >
            </C>
            <C index="0">
                <element index="0">one</element>
                <element index="1">two</element>
                <keyElement index="1">key</keyElement >
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

and I want to remove duplicates based on index value. I am already using a key for the **keyElement** which I am using in the iteration.

```
<xsl:key name="group-by-keyElement" match="C" use="keyElement" />
<xsl:for-each select="key('group-by-keyElement', keyElement )">
```

In the same iteration I need to remove the duplicates so that the output shows only once the values in C.

The result wanted is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C index="0">
                <element index="0">one</element>
                <element index="1">two</element>
                <keyElement index="1">key</keyElement >
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

Comment: You `keyElement` elements are empty so `use="keyElement"` does not seem to make sense. Also add the result you want to create with XSLT and of course start with Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml as the established XSLT 1.0 approach to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Your question is still not clear. What exactly defines a "duplicate"? If you're only looking at the string value of `keyElement`, then they will be duplicates even if the values of `element` and `index` are completely different - is that what you want? In any case, if you're using XSLT 1.0, start by trying Muenchian grouping and come back if you cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote: *I want to remove duplicates based on index value*.
I assume, you mean the value of *index* attribute in *C* tag.

Below you have a solution, working in both *XSLT 1.0* and *XSLT 2.0*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="indexKey" match="//C[@index]" use="@index" />

  <xsl:template match="C">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id(key('indexKey', @index)[1])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The key point is template matching *C* tag.

The first thing to do is to check whether the *id* generted for the current node
(`generate-id()`) is equal to the *id* generated for the first element
returned by `key` function from *key* named *indexKey* and value of
the current *index* attribute.

If this is the case, then:

- Make a (shallow) copy of the current element.
- Apply templates to the content of the current element.

Comment: Your answer does not need XSLT-2.0. It also works with XSLT-1.0. Correcting that would improve your answer.